# How to write Ant task for hibernate build-time bytecode enhancement

Tags: spring, hibernate, ant

I am trying to lazily fetch a child entity which is in a One to One association 
with the parent entity. I understood i have to activate hibernate build-time bytecode enhancement.

My project is built on Ant and i believe there is now support for Ant task 
contributed by Luis Barreiro. My challenge is that i am for now not proficient in writing
ant script. I have tried the much i can without luck. Child entity
although set to be lazily fetched is always eagerly fetched each time i try to 
retrieve just the Parent entity.

Here are my entity classes

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    //Basic properties excluded for brevity

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    private Child child;

    //getters and setters excluded for brevity

}

@Entity()
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child implements Serializable {

    //Basic properties excluded for brevity

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    //getters and setters excluded for brevity

}
```

Then my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyProject" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project MyProject.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

    <property name="lib.dir" value="./lib" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="./classes" />

    <path id="lib.class.path">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="enhance" depends="compile">
        <taskdef name="enhance" classname="org.hibernate.tool.enhance.EnhancementTask">
            <classpath path="${classes.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="lib.class.path"/>
        </taskdef>
        <enhance base="${classes.dir}" dir="${classes.dir}" 
             failOnError="true" 
             enableLazyInitialization="true" 
             enableDirtyTracking="true" 
             enableAssociationManagement="true" 
             enableExtendedEnhancement="true" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Please i need help on how to properly write the ant task to get this to work.
Any other observation aside the ant task should as well be pointed out.

NOTE: I can't use `optional = false` because Child entity is nullable.

Also note that i am using hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [this integration test](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/bytecode/BytecodeEnhancedOneToOneTest.java) in the `High-Performance Java Persistence` GitHub repository, the client-side does not use `@MapsId` because it interferes with the bytecode lazy fetching.

Also, the And task is not supported officially, only Maven and Gradle.

If you are using Hibernate 5.2, maybe you should migrate from Ant as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been trying not to migrate. Now this is the point I must have to migrate as you suggested. Once again thanks.